# Unable to serve static assets on rails 5.0. "super: no method `silence` for #<Logger:0x00000004bd78c0>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm pretty lost, so I'm not completely sure what would be useful information for this issue, but I'm trying to serve some static assets for an angular app in rails, including as my own and third party JS, HTML, and CSS. I've created a directory called `third_party` under `assets` where all my bower installed components go, and a directory called `my_app` for my own client code.

I require the necessary code in a `main_app.js` file in `app/assets/javascript`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular/angular

<snipped>

//= require_tree ../my_app/common
//= require main/index/index
//= require_tree ../my_app/main
```

I added those directories to the asset paths in my `application.rb` file with these lines:

`config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'third_party')
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'main_app')`

And added them to the precompile step in `assets.rb`:
`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( main_app.js )`

Finally I have an assets being served via a custom `assets_controller` that looks like this:

```
class AssetsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def serve_main_asset
    serve_asset_for_app("main")
  end

  protected

  def serve_asset_for_app(app_name)
    path = params[:path]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :file => "app/assets/my_app/#{app_name}/#{path}.html", layout:
          false }
      format.js { render :file => "#{path}.js" }
      format.css { render(:file => "#{path}.css") }
      format.json { render(:file => "app/assets/my_app/#{app_name}/#{path}.json") }
    end
  end
end
```

But whenever I try to `GET` any of these files, I'm seeing this error/stacktrace:

```
    2016-08-04 01:23:16 -0500: Rack app error handling request { GET /assets/main/index/index.html }
    #<NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `silence' for #<Logger:0x00000004bd78c0>>
    /home/pawan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/logger.rb:63:in `block (3 levels) in broadcast'
...
```

On a possibly related note, I notice that the app is also trying to serve assets with a unique filename, even though I thought I have all cache-busting logic turned off for development mode. (ex: `bootstrap.self-c8d853976ca268a5391a9470ebdcf3ba43e0b78936cdc925146afcb60a3116be.js`)

I feel like the issue may just be an outdated gem of some sort? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.

The problem was I used a plain Ruby Logger (config/environmens/development.rb):

```
config.logger = Logger.new('/dev/null')
```

To make it work, I've changed it to use an ActiveSupport Logger:

```
config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new('/dev/null')
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what it was. I actually managed to fix it a while back, but forgot to answer my own question... also forgot that I should replace that line with the active support logger rather than just leaving it commented out, heh, so thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of some recent changes in sprockets-rails gem, which is now offer a configuration option to silence asset request logging in development.

You can disable asset logging in your `development.rb` by setting below configuration.

`config.assets.quiet = false`

or use `ActiveSupport::Logger` instead.

`config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT))`